# Set/unset dgrid3d on the same graph

Tags: dataset, plot, gnuplot, interpolation, points

I would like to plot two different data sets on the same graph in 3d. This can easily be done with

```
splot 'foo.dat','bar.dat'
```

Unfortunately I would like `foo` to be smooth so I used `dgrid3d` to set a grid. At the same time I would like `bar` to just show dots (`foo` is actually an interpolation of `bar`, and I would like to plot the knots). Thus I used

```
set dgrid3d 20,20
splot 'foo.dat' w l, 'bar.dat' w points
```

Unfortunately this apply `dgrid3d` to both data sets... Is it possible to unset `dgrid3d` in the `splot` command or to solve this problem using another trick ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need another trick.  That trick is `set table`

```
set terminal push           #save terminal info
set terminal unknown        #null terminal
set table 'foo_gridded.dat' #temporary file to store the data
set dgrid3d 20,20   
splot 'foo.dat'
unset table                 #close temporary file
unset dgrid3d
set terminal pop            #restore terminal info
splot 'foo_gridded.dat' w l, 'bar.dat' w points  #make the plot we want
!rm foo_gridded.dat         #Optional, remove temporary file (Only works on Unix-like systems)
```

set table basically "plots" the data to a text file which is formatted for gnuplot to read back in.  It's **extremely useful** -- in the end, I think it's purpose is for creating all sorts of (ugly) little hacks like the one above so the gnuplot developers don't need to worry about plot-type clashes.  (I use this one to plot contours on top of pm3d maps).

Comment: @vanna : No problem.  I can't stress enough how useful a trick this is to keep in the back of your mind.  (If you look back through the posts here that I've answered on gnuplot, probably 1 out of 5 is just some variant of this trick).